# Use the Dates from a text file as options for a drop-down list

Tags: html, django

Im doing a simulation of prices and creating a page for it. The page will ask what year the user would like to simulate and the type of simulation to do (Monthly/weekly)

Based on the user's inputs, the page will open the text file that have filenames like this

```
2015_monthly.txt
2015_weekly.txt
2014_monthly.txt
2014_weekly.txt
```

Each file contains dates of when the simulation would end. For instance in 2015_monthly.txt

```
2015-01-30
2015-02-28
2015-03-31
.
.
.
```

What would i like to do is to ask the user to choose a date from the text file. I would like to do this in a dropdown list containing the dates from the file and use them as an options from a dropdown list. How can i translate this into a html code?

Comment: can you please add some relvent codes for this implementation?

Comment: I recommend that you do this in the front end meaning that if the user selects text one then you open text one with javascript and show the lines in a dropdown